# how to let jquery unwrap text if the link is uncomplete

Tags: jquery

I have a list of items and basically all should have a link and an image – but some don't. Since I can't check either via php I have to do it through jquery.

This is the actual html I'm refering to: two entries – first one with missing link and missing image – second entry has a working link ("/node/NUMBER") and an image ("/images/NUMBER-thumb.JPG")

```
<div class="related-entry">
    <a href="/node/">
      <div class="related-image">
        <img src="/images/-thumb.JPG"/>
      </div>
      <div class="related-term">term A</div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="related-entry">
    <a href="/node/64207">
      <div class="related-image">
        <img src="/images/64207-thumb.JPG"/>
      </div>
      <div class="related-term">term B</div>
    </a>
  </div>
```

This is the original function I used – it does remove the links – but also on the second item.

```
// remove 'empty' links
$("a").each(function() {
    var href = $(this).attr("href");
    if(href == '/node/') { 
         $('a').contents().unwrap();
    }
});
```

Removing empty image tags works perfectly fine – image tag for the first entry is hidden, second entry shows the image:

```
// remove empty images (works)
$("img").each(function() {
    var src = $(this).attr("src");
    if(src == '/images/-thumb.JPG') { 
    $(this).remove();
}
});
```

I also tried different aproaches – but either all links are removed, or none. Here's a version where I tried to 'communicate' the broken link through an empty id attribute:

```
// remove empty links (does not work)
$("a").each(function() {
if($(this).attr("id") == "") {
  $('a').contents().unwrap();
    }
});
```

What am i missing? greatful for any suggestions / pointers… Thnx!

Comment: What do you mean by empty links? You code is checking for links with attribute ID equals to string empty. You'd have better to provide relevant HTML markup in question itself

Comment: Can you add the HTML structure of the links, that would help finding the solution

Comment: thank you for the replies/ comments! I edited my question and added some example code and an additional function that i used – hope this makes my question clearer…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found it: instad of

```
 $('a').contents().unwrap();
```

it needs to be

```
 $(this).contents().unwrap();
```

so in context the function looks now like this:

```
 // remove empty links
 $("a").each(function() {
     var href = $(this).attr("href");
     if(href == '/node/') { // or anything else you want to remove...
         $(this).contents().unwrap();
     }
 });
```

…done.